# How do I display a Xamarin Forms Map in my project?

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin

I need to display a map with some markers (pins) in my Xamarin Forms app and according to docs.microsoft I can do it either this way:

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

```
namespace WorkingWithMaps
{
    public class MapTypesPageCode : ContentPage
    {
        public MapTypesPageCode()
        {
            Map map = new Map();
            Content = map;
        }
    }
}
```

or this way:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
    <maps:Map x:Name="map" />
</ContentPage>
```

but neither of them work, all I get is a blank screen. This is my code:

```
namespace iOS.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Map map = new Map();
            Content = map;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: Are you writing a Xamarin Forms app or a Xamarin iOS app?  If it's an iOS app, use MKMapView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/ios-maps/

Comment: It's a Xamarin Forms app :)

Comment: did you follow the docs for Initialization and Configuration?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

Comment: Ahh of course! That was my issue! Thanks a lot! <3